# date_query not returning some posts in date range

Tags: get-posts

I'm getting some very strange results with the date_query parameter of get_posts. I have a post for which:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i', get_post_time('U', false, $postid))
```

returns:

```
2014-04-03 10:42
```

This post is returned fine from get_posts with these arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => 41,
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
```

But *not* with these:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => '1980-01-01',
        'before' => '2100-01-01',
    ),
    'cat' => 41,
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
```

Other posts seem to come back fine. What could be up? Does date_query query something different to get_post_time?

Comment: Odd. Do you get the right post if you query JUST on the date_query? Have you tried wp_query instead of get_posts (shouldn't really make a difference but worth checking)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect for your [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters). It should be an array of an array, not just an array.

I also suspect that your problem might be related to PHP and not Wordpress.

Your `before` date is invalid. PHP only supports dates between 13 December  1901 and 19 January 2038, so your dates need to between those two dates. For reference, see [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

You would also want to include the 'inclusive' parameter and set it to `true` for exact matches

Your query should be something like

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after' => '1980-01-01',
        'before' => '2038-01-01',
        'inclusive' => true,
    ),
),
'cat' => 41,
'fields' => 'ids',
);
```